# Обработать и сохранить изображения в цикле

Tags: python, opencv

Как можно обработать и сохранить все изображения через цикл?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
from IPython.display import Image, display

f_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("H:/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
for imageName in glob.glob('H:/Для теста/*.jpg'):
    img = (Image(filename=imageName))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = f_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)
    for x, y, width, height in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)   
    cv2.imwrite("H:/Для теста/Тестированное/*.jpg", img)
```

То есть, все изображения из папки "Для теста" прогнать через цикл и записать с тем же именем в папку "Тестированное".

Comment: Причем здесь каскады, если у вас вопрос в работе с файлами?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так - откусываем имя файла с помощью `os.path.split` и присоединяем его к выходному имени каталога через `os.path.join`:

```
from os import path
...

for imageName in glob.glob('H:/Для теста/*.jpg'):
    ...
    outfile = path.join("H:/Для теста/Тестированное/", path.split(imageName)[1])
    cv2.imwrite(outfile, img)
```

Comment: Вроде переписал, ругается на строку gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY). Пишет: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: Так это вроде исправил. Теперь на outfile ругается, пишет expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray